# Getting Recommendation from Manager after resignation

Tags: resignation, references, asia

I am about a finish one year with my employer and my work permit is close to expiring.At this juncture, I have been assigned a driver level developement job which I cant do in a short time because of my lack of enough skills and my lack of interest in the work. I told them upfront the situation to avoid unnecessary problems for both sides and I asked for a department transfer which was rejected. So, I am now in a corner having no option but to leave the company.

My manager's reaction after this was "It is good that you have told us this before the start of  the project, but we have no choice to let you go". My notice period is 1 month and I have been forced to give my resignation and the notice period will be made shorter. But  I understand and accept the situation as it is normal in a professional environment. The manager has a good opinion on my character still.

**How can I ask for some more grace days so that I can get an another job?**

**Can I also ask for a recommendation letter from him?**

**Is it okay if I ask him personally for other job recommendations in other companies since he is a pioneer in the field?**

Comment: What kind of recommendation could you reasonably expect from a boss who fired you?

Comment: It is not a firing because of bad performance.It is only because I accept I cannot do the job which is above my skill level

Comment: Fair enough. But it sounds like the best grade he could give you is: 'Incomplete'.

Comment: I have made some edits to the question to try clear up exactly what you need. Please feel free to change them back if it has changes the question to much.

Comment: What country is this? I think there may be some strong cultural factors here which should be considered.

Comment: @enderland. Southeast Asia

Answer (score 2):

The grace days is a tricky one as you're asking for more time yet it'll still be rather limited.  This is a rather odd catch-22 in a sense that I'm not sure how you'd convince the employer that you'd still be of great value if you stay for another week or two.

While you can ask for a recommendation letter, this can go a few ways.  He may ask that you write the letter and he simply signs it.  He may turn you down.  There are a few unknowns here though I would consider asking him to be a reference as well as getting the recommendation letter.

You could ask for other opportunities that depending on how well he knows you, he may or may not pass along your information.  Again, it is worth asking but understand that there are lots of different possible results here as it could be that he doesn't have many contacts where there are openings for you.  The pioneers can sometimes be the loose cannons as they discover new fields and go into uncharted territory.

If you require a work permit to work in the country legally, this could really be a challenge to overcome in some places since different countries may have different policies on how to handle foreign workers.

Answer (score -4):

It's unlikely they are going to keep you around for any longer than the agreed time period.  You can always ask, but if you're not interested in doing the work they assigned you, it's pretty much over.

If they know you are technically competent but a bad match for what they wanted, it is likely they will give you a recommendation that a new employer would like.  If they don't think you're technically competent the wording of the recommendation letter might sound glowing, but would contain vague generalities.  They might even list accomplishments, but these 'accomplishments' took a whole year?  In short, such a letter might be poisonous.

You can ask him for job recommendations, and he may give you some, but you may discover these are useless, and he told you whatever you wanted to hear.

In short, the larger message is you're hoping someone will help you find another job. To the extent this is possible at all, such jobs tend to be miserable.  I can tell you there are jobs available in big box retail stores are greeters and custodians.  For some reason this doesn't look like an objective on your career path.

I am reading stories where people that do nothing more than HTML and CSS are making $80,000+, although I suspect this is in high rent districts and may not apply to where you are.  There are shops that do nothing more than create wireframes and static content and then leave it up to other developers (often in other organizations) to put code behind it.  In short, you could probably muddle through without any programming skills at all if you're willing to simply design forms.  Since I am presuming you do have some programming, work that involves relatively 'low intensity coding', whatever that means in your context, might be the appropriate next step.

If someone asks for work that involves only light amounts of programming, and you tell them that you tried heavier duty tasks and found it more than you had the stomach for, you'll work out fine.  Just be prepared to explain what you want and what you think you can do.

Comment: The OP was after advice on how to ask for more time in his current job so he could seek a new one as well if he can or can not ask for a letter of reference. This answer seems to be more about the next possible job and what the reference letters contents might be about.

Comment: "Nothing more than HTML and CSS?"  Design professionals who can use HTML and CSS to produce an attractive web site are hard to find.